# rescaling the window and widget depending on screen resolution in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

I designed and implemented an application in Qt ... I wanted to fix the window size so I made the mistake of hard coding the places of the widgets on the window in all the different screens.

Now the application is done and it works perfectly on my screen (or any screen with 1920*1080) resolution... but when I tried on a 4k screen the window looks tiny.. lower resolutions makes it look big as well.

so the question is.. How can I rescale the whole application.. the window with all the buttons and widgets on it depending on the physical screen pixel density without redesigning all the screens?
maybe calculating a scaling factor depending on the screen resolution like:

```
qreal refDpi = 216.;
qreal refHeight = 1776.;
qreal refWidth = 1080.;
QRect rect = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry();
qreal height = qMax(rect.width(), rect.height());
qreal width = qMin(rect.width(), rect.height());
qreal dpi = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->logicalDotsPerInch();
m_ratio = qMin(height/refHeight, width/refWidth);
m_ratioFont = qMin(height*refDpi/(dpi*refHeight), width*refDpi/(dpi*refWidth));
```

and the using setViewport as mentioned [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/coordsys.html#window-viewport-conversion)

```
painter.setViewport(x, y, width*ScaleFactor, height* ScaleFactor);
```

but where to use that?

All my screens inherits QWidget.. so maybe I can make a new class MyQWidget and overload the render function to implement the rescale?

Comment: Don't try to find some obscure workaround, it will not work. Recreate/modify the UI and use layout managers.

Comment: @musicamante That would be my last solution... also I have a very customized GUI where I move the elements around dynamically to specific positions as interactions to user behavior... layouts make it very hard to place the elements in custom positions, it is either horizontal, vertical or a grid..
right now all I need is a scaling factor for the whole application.. I am sure it can be done somehow